# Image in heroku uploaded using paperclip does not show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip

I uploaded an image to heroku through paperclip. Image when once uploaded come in show properly, I am using this tag:

```
 <%= image_tag d.avatar.url %>
```

Intially first time when I upload it it appears on the app, but when I close it and open it again in place of image, only its name appears.The source code is this:

```
<img alt="Best-meme-and-troll-1-1-s-307x512" src="/system/documents/avatars/528b/b238/8f6c/c256/d000/0004/original/best-meme-and-troll-1-1-s-307x512.jpg?1384886840" />
```

I think when I upload the image its only store its name, size, location and type. If this is true how can I show picture on server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku keeps paperclip uploaded images for few minutes then automatically removes them, it only keeps images residing in assets. To keep docs or images you need amazon s3 or other web services

Comment: So I should use amazon s3?